# In Darcs, view diff between two patches

Tags: darcs

In Git, I can view the diff between two commits by running something like:

```
$ git diff c23a45 ffd644
```

How do I do this in Darcs?

Following [section 5.10.1 of the user manual](http://darcs.net/manual/darcs.pdf) I have tried:

```
$ darcs diff --from-patch ffd644 --to-patch c23a45
```

but this gives the error:

```
darcs: Couldn't find patch matching "patch-name ffd644"
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Darcs/Patch/Match.hs:654:43 in darcs-2.12.4-EYDQyfVEyiPHocMCwLEEKg:Darcs.Patch.Match
```

I get a similar error when using the full patch hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to patches by their hashes, use `--from-hash` and `--to-hash`:

```
darcs diff --from-hash ffd644 --to-hash c23a45
```

You can also use the more verbose `match` syntax:

```
darcs diff --from-match 'hash ffd644' --to-match 'hash c23a45'
```

Note that this is an *inclusive* selection: you'll see a diff that includes all the patches between and including the two you specify.

The set of patches included will also depend on the order the patches currently are in your repository. If you reorder the patches, e.g. with `darcs optimize reorder` or by pulling them into a different repository, then you might see a different diff.